# have to JSON.parse twice to extract json object from stringified QR Code

Tags: json, typescript, react-native

I have some JSON

```
{
    id: "abcd",
    type: "receive"
}
```

which I stringified and generated a QR code using some online QR code maker. In my react native app, I am using `react-native-qrcode-scanner` to scan this qr code which calls an `onSuccess(qrCode: Event)` function.

I've set up the function as follows:

```js
function onSuccess(qrCode: Event) {
    console.log(qrCode.data);
    const parsedData = JSON.parse(qrCode.data);
    console.log(parsedData);
    console.log(typeof parsedData);
    console.log(parsedData.id);
    const parsedData2 = JSON.parse(parsedData);
    console.log(parsedData2.id);
    navigation.navigate('Home');
  }
```

This gives the following output

```
"{\"type\":\"receive\",\"id\":\"abcd\"}"
{"type":"receive","id":"abcd"}
string
undefined
abcd
```

So basically, `qrCode.data` is a `string` which is expected. `parsedData` outputs like an object, but has `typeof` `string`. Accessing properties on `parsedData` gives `undefined` - which makes sense if it's a string. When I parse it a second time into `parsedData2` that is an object and I can access properties on it.

My confusion is, why is it not just parsing it the first time? Why do I have to do it twice?